# Resizing border bottom

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to resize the border bottom to half so it's align to the link students. How can i resize that? im trying to resize but just the thickness is moving not the length. You can see the picture above.

here is my html code.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
        </button>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/brandz.png" >
    </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                         <div class="modal-content">
                             <div class="modal-header">
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                             </div>
                             <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                             </div>
                             <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is my css

```
       .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
       font-weight: 590;
       color: #949494;
       display: block;
       padding: 5px 35px 2px 45px;
       border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
       line-height: 97px;
       text-decoration: none;
       transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out; 

       }
       .navbar-default{
       background-color:#fff;

       }
       .nav>li>a {
       position: relative;
       }
      .navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
       padding-left: 70px;
       padding-right: 1px;
       }
       .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
       background-color: #000000;
       margin:0 0 4px;
       width: 25px;
       height: 5px;

       }

       .nav.navbar-nav > li{
       display: :inline-block;
       }
       .nav.navbar-nav{
       list-style-type:none;
       }
       .nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
       color:#a92419;
       border-bottom-color: #a92419;
       }

      .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      background-color:#a92419 ;
      margin:0 0 4px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 5px;

      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-  toggle:hover        { 
      background: none;
      }
      button.navbar-toggle{
      background:none;
      border:none;
      color:#000;

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it already by this.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a margin instead of padding

you have:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
   padding-left: 70px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   }
```

instead of the padding left being 70px try:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
   margin-left: 70px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   }
```

That should leave all the space to the left

Comment: @TikboyPengan This answers your question. The problem with your code is that you use padding to separate the navbar list items. Padding just increases the actual size of the element, making the border fit around the padding. Using margin should fix it.